# Py.test runner on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, jython, pytest

Py.test version 2.5.2
Java 8
Jython 2.7
Eclipse 4.3.2
PyDev 3.5.0

I am trying to write some Jython for a project. Currently I am unable to run py.test runner on eclipse to test my code. Whenever I try, I get this output: Warning: Could not import the test runner: --py-test-params. Running with the default pydev unittest runner instead.

Clearly its using the PyDev test runner. I thought installing PyDev 3.5.0 through eclipse would allow me to use py.test. Is there some extra paths I need to configure in Eclipse?

Comment: Nevermind. In my run configurations, it wasn't set to my default working directory.